# Cholesky factorization counterexample

Tags: matrices, examples-counterexamples, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

Could you give a counter example of a symetric matrix for which the Cholesky factorization
does not exist?

Also why does any eigenvalue solver have to be iterative?

Comment: $[-1]$ is a symmetric $1\times1$ matrix.

Comment: The Abel–Ruffini states (very roughly) that, in general, there are no algebraic solutions for finding roots of a polynomial degree 5 and higher. Since an eigenvalue solver could be used to find roots of a polynomial, the same applies. Hence, in general, iterative methods must be used. (Special cases always exist, of course, that allow direct methods to be used.)

Comment: Please ask one question at a time, or explain how the questions are related and why you think they should be answered in a single thread. In the present case, both of the above comments could have been posted as answers to one of your questions, and presumably weren't posted as answers because they would have been incomplete. This exemplifies one reason why separate questions should be posted separately (another being that it facilitates searching for questions and answers).

Comment: the system does not allow me to ask my question because of low quality what ever that means...

Comment: Wait did you just edit the question into a completely different new question?

Comment: it is changed to old version it is fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $M$ has a Cholesky decomposition $M=L^TL$, then $M$ must be symmetric positive-semidefinite, since
   $$x^TMx = (Lx)^T(Lx) = \|Lx\|^2\geq0.$$
   Since every symmetric positive-semidefinite matrix has a Cholesky decomposition, this is a complete characterization.
2. As copper.hat points out in his comment, finding the eigenvalues of a matrix is equivalent to finding the roots of its characteristic polynomial. For matrices larger than $4\times 4$, by the Abel-Ruffini Theorem there does not exist a general formula for these roots in terms of addition, multiplication, and rational powers. That does *not* mean that a direct eigenvalue algorithm cannot exist -- but such an algorithm would have to be "sufficiently complex" and is not yet known.